# Dedicated Sitecore CM publishing instance in a load balanced environment

Tags: c#, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

We need to setup a load balanced CM environment for Sitecore - mainly for failover purposes, but also for times when the load might get too heavy. We are going to have two servers for this. I was going through the scaling guide, and they mention that in a load balanced CM environment, it is necessary to have one server dedicated to publishing. The remark states that it is mainly for performance, but I've heard people state that unless you setup the dedicated publishing instance, the publishing queues doesn't get synchronized. I guess I understand this, based on how the sitecore publishing queue works, but what is the point of having a load balanced CM environment if there is a dependency on one of the servers? Granted its not a 'site down' dependency, but its a dependency none the less - is there a way around this?

**Edit**

I have a few answers here that all point to the fact that it may be a performance issue or a deadlock issue, so I guess my real question is, how do you make a failover for the dedicated publishing instance, because now a singular publishing instance will become a central point of failure.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason from my understanding is to synchronize and handle the event queues. The CM server would send its local events to the publishing server which would in turn handle those events, publish and fire off remote events. The event queue would get extremely difficult to synchronize if both servers would be able to publish, given that 2 publish events could fire almost simultaneously from both CM servers if there was no dedicated publish server.

Performance is also a consideration, but this is also the case if you have a single publish server. Content editors will notice a usability issue while this is running. This is why the recommendation is ideally a 3 server CM setup would be best: 2 CM instances and 1 publish instance on which no authoring is carried out. This would also allow you (on Sitecore 7.2) to [setup parallel publishing](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Reinnovations/Posts/2014/03/Parallel-Publishing.aspx) but this is not always realistic and you still have that dependency on one of the servers as you rightly state. But given the issue with the event queue, even if you had 10 servers, you I think you will need that dependency somewhere.

I recently read this old post on [Configure a authoring server as publishing instance](http://www.newguid.net/sitecore/2012/configure-a-authoring-server-as-publishing-instance/) which had some really nice information.

I've only read around this and hopefully someone with more practical experience will answer shortly, but when I've been thinking about this the only conclusion I came to was if the "wrong" CM instance was to fail then the `Publishing.PublishingInstance` setting would have to be updated. Maybe have a patch config(.disabled) ready so you could deploy/rename it when needed and put that as one of the steps in your disaster recovery plan. Some manual intervention is obviously required and as you say, it is not a "site down" dependency. With most projects I've worked on this is acceptable, the front end servers in that situation was always the priority.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity, if you load-balance the CM environment, you must configure only one of the instances in that environment to publish. I don't remember the exact details of why, but this could be for performance, to eliminate deadlocks, to minimize redundant publishing chaos and cache clearing, and for other reasons. That instance is in the balance processing HTTP requests from CMS users, but it's the only instance in that  environment that performs publication. I agree that if the publishing instance fails, the setting must change, although I would have to look at the implementation to see if there is some way to fallback or apply logic to determine the publishing instance instead of just using the setting.

This is different than a dedicated publishing instance, which sits in the CM environment but not in the balance. That is for scenarios which have very high volumes of publishing, to offload the publishing overhead from instances in the balance.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Sitecore "[Scaling Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/scaling_guide_sc70_a4.pdf)" document, Page 27

> The publishing CM instance can still be an authoring instance, or it
>   can also be used as a dedicated instance that is solely responsible
>   for publishing. The latter option can be used to separate the
>   publishing from the authoring CM instances for performance reasons,
>   deployment strategy, or for other considerations. Publish operations
>   can be initiated from any CM instance in the environment. They are
>   queued, and then the publishing instance picks them up as a sequence

So, mainly for performance, deployment and other consideration, also this is not a 'Load Balance' setup, as sitecore call it Multi-Instance setup, which means authors will login to each instance separately, and not let the load balance server determine which CM instance to use.